# Get information of more than one youtube video by id from one request?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Can I get information of more than one youtube video from one request using youtube api (ver 2.0)?

[Retrieving information about a single video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=zh-TW#Retrieve_video_entry)

From above link, I can know how to get information of `single` video by its id. For example:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ylLzyHk54Z0?v=2&fields=title,author,yt:statistics,yt:rating&alt=json

But how can I get two videos information by their ids from one request? I have read the developer guide and it seems that there is nothing about my question. Is youtube api version 3.0 able to do this?

Hope anyone can help!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [YouTube API v2.0 – Using Batch Processing](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing).

You may post an XML like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <batch:operation type="query" />
    <entry>
        <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/weRefE-qw9</id>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kkT-t894YSa</id>
    </entry>
    ...
</feed>
```

To this URL:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/batch
```

This is a quote from documentation:

> The YouTube Data API supports batch processing, enabling you to
>   execute up to 50 operations with a single API request rather than
>   submit a separate request for each individual operation. A batch
>   processing request can combine multiple query (GET), insert (POST),
>   update (PUT) and delete (DELETE) operations. Each operation is
>   contained within an `<entry>` tag in the request. This section explains
>   how to format batch processing requests and handle the API responses
>   to those requests.

Comment: Does youtube batch processing accept POST request only?
Is it possible to accept GET request?